# Windsor register a component with different keys?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am trying to register a component with different keys but it seems that for this to work, i need to duplicate the registration i.e. multiple registration of the same component, each with a different key.

```
        IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For<INotificationDataLoader>().ImplementedBy<NotificationDataLoader>().Named(NotificationTypeEnum.Create.Id.ToString()));
        IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For<INotificationDataLoader>().ImplementedBy<NotificationDataLoader>().Named(NotificationTypeEnum.Cancel.Id.ToString()));
        IocManager.IocContainer.Register(Component.For<INotificationDataLoader>().ImplementedBy<NotificationDataLoader>().Named(NotificationTypeEnum.Expire.Id.ToString()));
```

Is it possible to register the component only once and able to resolve based on different keys?

Comment: A component has a single, unique key. What are you _really_ trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I understand that and i am not trying to violate the unique key constraint. This is a business need, such that a specific loader will be used based on those values. I could of course work around this and specify a key for all of those values, but i wanted a solution in the same manner of registering a component.

Comment: Do the loaders differ in any way? How would using marker interfaces instead suit your requirements?

In general it's fairly uncommon to specify or worry about component's id/name

Comment: Of course the loaders will differ. I just showed an example of registering the same component with three different keys. There will be other loaders and other keys. As for the interface, i am trying to achieve something dynamic, such that based on the, resolve the target loader.